# Remove empty lines made by grep inside a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, grep, lines, string

I'm searching for a way to get this to work:
I want it to give all matches that he finds without making empty lines if he doesn't find something

```
lines=($(cat fee.file | awk '{print $1}'))
for line in ${lines[@]}; do

dropper="$(cat foo.file | grep ${checkvar[$nr]})"

((nr++))
done

echo $dropper
```

It gives me:

```
 4594

 4044


 4950




 4503
```

Now I only want to do a action when there is a number, and I want to do nothing when it is empty.
So I add this in the for loop

```
if ! [[ -z $dropper ]]; then
echo $dropper
fi
```

but this doesn't work. it still prints the empty lines on my screen! 
somehow even if grep does not find something it fills $droppers with something. I even tryed removing the white lines with sed, grep or awk.. but nothing helps.

how do I only activate the if statement when $droppers is actually filled?

The foo.file is just filled with lots of lines with only numbers.. Like:

```
4594
4595
4597
2489
3949
```

The fee.file would have same numbers but about 10% of the numbers match to numbers in foo.file

Comment: Which shell are you using? Could you post some example for `foo.file` and a *working* script?

Comment: I think it is debian version 7, and the foo file is just filled with a long list of numbers. nothing special.

Comment: Could you issue `echo $SHELL` and post the result?

Comment: It doesn't give me anything.. only /bin/bash

Comment: So, you are using Bash as shell ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok.. srry will change title if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read number remainder
do
  dropper="$(grep -w $number foo.file)"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$dropper found"
  else 
    echo "$number not found"
  fi
done < "fee.file"
```

If filled `fee.file` and `foo.file` with

```
for i in $(seq 1 100 1001); do echo $i some other stuff >> fee.file; done
for i in $(seq 1 1000); do echo $i >> foo.file; done
```

My output is:

```
1 found
101 found
201 found
301 found
401 found
501 found
601 found
701 found
801 found
901 found
1001 not found
```

In your case you could replace the do loop by `for number in ${lines[@]}; do ... done`.

Comment: OMG! ITS WORKING.. ya have no idea how long I have been eating on this
I love you.. thanks.
Can you please explain the $? -eq 0
and do you know maybe how I set a variable on NULL... I'm not really sure if I used that right eighter in one if my try's

Comment: The whole [ $? -eq 0 ] $$ stuf is kinda new for me. how do I turn this into a if "do action1" else "do action2"?

Comment: `$?` contains the exit code of the last command. So if `grep` fails, `$?` is non-zero.

Comment: I already changed the code into an `if ... then ... else` construct.

Comment: Use `unset var` to unset a variable `var` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The following will print the matching lines from foo.file for every input number in fee.file. You may be trying to do something more complex which isn't clear from your post; if that's the case let me know.

```
lines=($(cat fee.file | awk '{print $1}'))

for line in ${lines[@]}; do
    grep $line foo.file;
done;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ya response!, 
You are almost there. What I basicly want is comparing 2 files loads of reandom numbers and give me the once that are in both files.
For some more complex reason, and for speed I want to use grep to directly grep the matching numbers and print it. 

Finally I want a if statement to do action1 if he finds a matching number, or do action2 if he coudn't find a matching number.